# Can we use command in ternary operator (Java)?

Tags: java, operator-keyword, ternary

This is a working code:

```
String a = "first";
String b = "second";
String object;
System.out.println(object != null ? a : b);
```

But it isn't:

```
String a = "first";
String b = "second";
String object;
object != null ? System.out.println(a) : System.out.println(b);
```

Why?

Comment: Cause the first uses expressions and the second uses statements. That's why it's called an operator, it's used in expressions.

Answer (score 3):

A per the [spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand expression to be an invocation of a void method.

`println` is a method from the `PrintStream` class (which `System.out` is an instance of) and it has a return type of `void`.

Consider that the operator itself is expected to return something for use in cases such as:

```
 bool a = true;
 int b = a ? 1 : 2;
```

If you give a method returning `void` (i.e. nothing) as the second and/or third expression, what would the operator itself return?

Finally, Java has no lexical structure that is called a "command". `System.out.println` is a method invocation like any other, it just doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator should always return a value, whereas in case of SysOut the return type is void.